# Proper way to query from 2 tables while giving hierarchy to one table.

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently trying to obtain data from two tables that have the same columns. The values for primary key "ID" of both tables may exist in one or both tables. Even with same primary keys, the values in different columns may not be the same for both tables. My question is given I have an ID testID, how do I query where in I first check table1 if it exists. If it exists in table1 I use the details found in table1, otherwise check table2 and use details in table2 if it exists in table2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
select 
  case when t1.id is not null then t1.field1 else t2.field1 end as field1, 
  case when t1.id is not null then t1.field2 else t2.field2 end as field2, 
  ...
from table1 t1
full outer join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where t1.id = :testid or t2.id = :testid;
```

Or UNION ALL in combination with NOT EXISTS:

```
select field1, field2, ...
from table1
where id = :testid
union all
select field1, field2, ...
from table2
where id = :testid and not exists (select * from table1 where id = :testid);
```

Answer (score 1):

The possible way is to use FULL OUTER JOIN

```
 SELECT t1.id,
   t2.id,
   CASE
     WHEN t1.id IS NOT NULL
     AND t2.id  IS NOT NULL
     THEN 'ID in both sources'
     WHEN t1.id IS NULL
     THEN 'ID in T2 only'
     WHEN t2.id IS NULL
     THEN 'ID in T1 only'
   END source_key
 FROM t1
 FULL OUTER JOIN t2
 ON t1.id    = t2.id
 WHERE t1.id = 1 -- your test_id here
 OR t2.id    = 1;  -- your test_id here
```

Cheching if T1.ID/ T2.ID is not NULL you get the information if the record is defined in the respective source table.